# C# 7 and Tuple casting through event aggregator

Tags: c#, .net, tuples

In C# 7 tuples became powerful:

```
var tuple = (speed: 45, color: "red");
```

Coupled with an event aggregator:

```
        EvtAgreg.Publish("SomeInfo", (
            speed:     45,
            color: "red",
        ));
```

That would be very powerful to make decoupled code. However, from what I've gathered it seems impossible to recast that.

```
EvtAgreg.Subscribe("SomeInfo", this.GetType().Name, (obj) => {
       var data = ((int, string)) obj;
}
```

However, this is not flexible and was wondering if there might be another way to cast on runtime similar to JS.

```
EvtAgreg.Subscribe("SomeInfo", this.GetType().Name, (obj) => {
       var data = (?) obj;
       data.speed ... or data["speed"]       
}
```

Obviously that isn't possible, however, would it be through a class holding the tuple and its format (Type) ?

---

Edit: Trying to bring clarity about the question.

It is not about casting, but how to make the casting simple.

The point is, if you have a complex dataset of say 20 values that can be of different types, the casting becomes something like

```
var x = ((string, int, int, int, float, string, string, int, int, int, string, int, int, int, float, string, string, int, int, int)) obj;
```

Which becomes impossible to maintain.

Here is a way to achieve something similar with Hashtable:

Publisher:

```
            MessageManager.Publish("Hardware_NewIRInfos",
                new Hashtable() {
                {   "position", i },
                {   "status",   (int)Load.IRStatus(i) },
                {   "serial",   (int)Load.IRSerial(i) },
                {   "id",       (int)Load.IRID(i) },
                {   "version",  Load.IRVersion(i) },
                {   "cal",      (int)Load.IRCalDate(i) },
                {   "emissivity",    Load.IREmissivity(i) },
                {   "transmissivity",Load.IRTransmissivity(i) },
                {   "gain",     Load.IRGain(i) },
                {   "offset",   Load.IROffset(i) }
            });
```

Subscriber:

```
    MessageManager.Subscribe("Hardware_NewIRInfos", this.GetType().Name, (obj) =>
    {
        Hashtable data = (Hashtable)obj;

        IRSensorParameters[pos ].Channel = pos;
        IRSensorParameters[pos ].Status  = (int) data["status"];
        IRSensorParameters[pos ].ID      = (int)data["id"]; ;
        IRSensorParameters[pos ].Serial  = (int) data["serial"]; 
        IRSensorParameters[pos ].Version = (string)data["version"]; 
        IRSensorParameters[pos ].CalibrationDate = (int) data["cal"]; 
        IRSensorParameters[pos ].Emissivity = (float)data["emissivity"]; 
        IRSensorParameters[pos ].Transmissivity = (float)data["transmissivity"]; 
        IRSensorParameters[pos ].Gain = (float)data["gain"]; 
        IRSensorParameters[pos ].Offset = (float)data["offset"]; 
    });
```

In here you still have static casting, but it is much easier to maintain.

Is it possible to have a similar, better way, using C# 7 Tuples?

Comment: Just create a type for it, and you are free of any casting problems ;) Types are the reason you are using c#

Comment: Create a type then creates code dependencies, that is the point of using a tuple instead of a model, otherwise can just create a class, this is what I try to avoid.

Comment: Tuple is also a dependency (hidden dependency, which is worse). Type can be in shared library and be in one place, so publisher and subscriber don't need to "know" about each other.

Comment: Yes, but they still both need to know about the shared library so it creates coupling there.

Comment: Why not serialize it to json, pass as a string and deserialize on subscriber side then ;)

Comment: Its a solution but performance-wise it's very heavy. @Fabio.

Comment: _Is it possible to have a similar, better way, using C# 7 Tuples_ - No, better way would be using types ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing one set of brackets:

```
var data = ((int, string)) obj;
```

Think of it like this: 
to cast you write `(MyType)obj` so casting requires set of brackets,

to declare tuple you wirite  `(int, string)` so it requires its own set of brackets,

it cannot be the same set of brackets so you get double.

[image]

---

as long as your inner types match you can cast to whatever named properties you want:

```
var a = ((int speed, string color))(3,"red");
var c = ((int someInt, string someString))a;
var color = c.someString;
```

[image]

Also you can always use generic names `Item1` `Item2` they are not hinted by intellisense but are valid. There is no (easy) way to convert it to array but you have constant there either way so this should be fine.

One more nice thing is tuple expansion you can just unload it to variables in one line:

```
var tuple =(speed: 4, color: "red");
var (number, text) = tuple;
```

---

So yes tuples become hard to wrap you head around fast. And I would use them only for private in class communication between methods just because it does not require formal type declaration. Your use of tuple with 20 items is just wrong. Do not do that. In my opinion 4 items in tuple is too much and warrant dedicated type creation. If you really want such very fragile setup you can use your code exactly as you have written `Hashtable` is valid c# class. I would just create dedicated type.

So the bottom line is no you cannot have this using tuple just create dedicated class or use already defined type - whatever is in `IRSensorParameters[pos]`. To avoid dependency you can send string that contains your data eg. in json format.

Comment: Yes it does need a set of brackets (question edited). However this answer doesn't address the question.

Comment: @Damien is this what you are after? If not you need to rephrase the question.

Comment: My question is about dynamic, or clear casting, I will try to rephrase with an example.